# spring hibernate javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

My project is giving me an error after adding one property `endDate` and it's `getter & setter` to entity `Project`:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'endDate' not found on type com.mvc.project.bean.Project
```

my project bean is as follows:

```
package com.mvc.project.bean;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @Column
    private String aldonNumber;
    //@Id
    @Column
    private String ITPRNumber;  


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="subtrackID") 
    private Subtrack subtrack ; 

    @Column
    private String releaseType;
    @Column
    private String releaseDate;
    @Column
    private String projName;

    @Column
    private String projStatus;
    @Column
    private String projType;
    @Column
    private String startDate;
    /*@Column
    private String projName;*/
    @Column
    private String endDate; 
    @Column
    private String devVendor;
    @Column
    private String QAVendor;
    @Column
    private String ISManager;

    @Column
    private String caremarkPM;   
    @Column
    private String onsiteDevTechLead;
    @Column
    private String offshoreDevTechLead;
    @Column
    private String onsiteQALead;
    @Column
    private String offshoreQALead;
    @Column
    private String projOwner;
    @Column
    private String onsiteDevPM;
    @Column
    private String offshoreDevPM;
    @Column
    private String onsiteQAPM;
    @Column
    private String offshoreQAPM;
    @Column
    private String submittedDate;
    @Column
    private String approvedDate;
    @Column
    private String createdDate;
    @Column
    private String createdBy;
    @Column
    private String lastModifieddate;
    @Column
    private String lastModifiedby;



    /**
     * @param aldonNumber
     * @param ITPRNumber
     * @param releaseType
     * @param releaseDate
     * @param projDesc
     * @param trackID
     * @param subtrackID
     * @param approverID
     * @param projStatus
     * @param projType
     * @param startDate
     * @param projName
     * @param devVendor
     * @param qAVendor
     * @param iSManager
     * @param projOwner
     * @param submittedDate
     * @param approvedDate
     * @param createdDate
     * @param createdBy
     * @param lastModifieddate
     * @param lastModifiedby
     */
    public Project() {}
    public Project(String aldonNumber, String ITPRNumber, String releaseType,
            String releaseDate, String projName, Subtrack subtrack,
            String subtrackID,String projStatus, String projType,
            String startDate,String endDate,  String devVendor,
            String qAVendor,String ISManager,String caremarkPM,String onsiteDevTechLead, String offshoreDevTechLead,String onsiteQALead, String offshoreQALead,String onsiteDevPM, String offshoreDevPM,String onsiteQAPM, String offshoreQAPM, String projOwner,
            String submittedDate, String approvedDate, String createdDate,
            String createdBy, String lastModifieddate, String lastModifiedby) {
        super();
        this.aldonNumber = aldonNumber;
        this.ITPRNumber = ITPRNumber;
        this.releaseType = releaseType;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.projName = projName;
        this.subtrack = subtrack;
        this.projStatus = projStatus;
        this.ISManager = ISManager;
        this.projType = projType;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate=endDate;
        /*this.projName = projName;*/
        this.devVendor = devVendor;
        this.QAVendor = qAVendor;

        this.caremarkPM = caremarkPM;
        this.onsiteDevTechLead = onsiteDevTechLead;
        this.offshoreDevTechLead = offshoreDevTechLead;
        this.onsiteQALead = onsiteQALead;
        this.offshoreQALead = offshoreQALead;
        this.projOwner = projOwner;
        this.onsiteDevPM = onsiteDevPM;
        this.offshoreDevPM = offshoreDevPM;
        this.onsiteDevPM = onsiteDevPM;
        this.onsiteQAPM = onsiteQAPM;
        this.offshoreQAPM = offshoreQAPM;
        this.submittedDate = submittedDate;
        this.approvedDate = approvedDate;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.lastModifieddate = lastModifieddate;
        this.lastModifiedby = lastModifiedby;
    }


    public String getAldonNumber() {
        return aldonNumber;
    }
    public void setAldonNumber(String aldonNumber) {
        this.aldonNumber = aldonNumber;
    }
    public String getITPRNumber() {
        return ITPRNumber;
    }
    public void setITPRNumber(String ITPRNumber) {
        this.ITPRNumber = ITPRNumber;
    }
    public String getReleaseType() {
        return releaseType;
    }
    public void setReleaseType(String releaseType) {
        this.releaseType = releaseType;
    }
    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }
    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }
    public String getProjName() {
        return projName;
    }
    public String getOnsiteDevPM() {
        return onsiteDevPM;
    }
    public void setOnsiteDevPM(String onsiteDevPM) {
        this.onsiteDevPM = onsiteDevPM;
    }
    public String getOffshoreDevPM() {
        return offshoreDevPM;
    }
    public void setOffshoreDevPM(String offshoreDevPM) {
        this.offshoreDevPM = offshoreDevPM;
    }
    public String getOnsiteQAPM() {
        return onsiteQAPM;
    }
    public void setOnsiteQAPM(String onsiteQAPM) {
        this.onsiteQAPM = onsiteQAPM;
    }
    public String getOffshoreQAPM() {
        return offshoreQAPM;
    }
    public void setOffshoreQAPM(String offshoreQAPM) {
        this.offshoreQAPM = offshoreQAPM;
    }
    public void setProjName(String projName) {
        this.projName = projName;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public Subtrack getSubtrack() {
        return subtrack;
    }
    public void setSubtrack(Subtrack subtrack) {
        this.subtrack = subtrack;
    }
    /*public String getProjName() {
        return projName;
    }
    public void setProjName(String projName) {
        this.projName = projName;
    }*/
    /*public String getTrackID() {
        return trackID;
    }
    public void setTrackID(String trackID) {
        this.trackID = trackID;
    }*/

    public String getProjStatus() {
        return projStatus;
    }
    public void setProjStatus(String projStatus) {
        this.projStatus = projStatus;
    }
    public String getProjType() {
        return projType;
    }
    public void setProjType(String projType) {
        this.projType = projType;
    }
    public String getDevVendor() {
        return devVendor;
    }
    public void setDevVendor(String devVendor) {
        this.devVendor = devVendor;
    }
    public String getQAVendor() {
        return QAVendor;
    }
    public void setQAVendor(String qAVendor) {
        QAVendor = qAVendor;
    }
    public String getISManager() {
        return ISManager;
    }
    public void setISManager(String iSManager) {
        ISManager = iSManager;
    }

    public String getCaremarkPM() {
        return caremarkPM;
    }
    public void setCaremarkPM(String caremarkPM) {
        this.caremarkPM = caremarkPM;
    }
    public String getOnsiteDevTechLead() {
        return onsiteDevTechLead;
    }
    public void setOnsiteDevTechLead(String onsiteDevTechLead) {
        this.onsiteDevTechLead = onsiteDevTechLead;
    }
    public String getOffshoreDevTechLead() {
        return offshoreDevTechLead;
    }
    public void setOffshoreDevTechLead(String offshoreDevTechLead) {
        this.offshoreDevTechLead = offshoreDevTechLead;
    }
    public String getOnsiteQALead() {
        return onsiteQALead;
    }
    public void setOnsiteQALead(String onsiteQALead) {
        this.onsiteQALead = onsiteQALead;
    }
    public String getOffshoreQALead() {
        return offshoreQALead;
    }
    public void setOffshoreQALead(String offshoreQALead) {
        this.offshoreQALead = offshoreQALead;
    }
    public String getProjOwner() {
        return projOwner;
    }
    public void setProjOwner(String projOwner) {
        this.projOwner = projOwner;
    }

    public String getSubmittedDate() {
        return submittedDate;
    }
    public void setSubmittedDate(String submittedDate) {
        this.submittedDate = submittedDate;
    }
    public String getApprovedDate() {
        return approvedDate;
    }
    public void setApprovedDate(String approvedDate) {
        this.approvedDate = approvedDate;
    }
    public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }
    public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }
    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
    public String getLastModifieddate() {
        return lastModifieddate;
    }
    public void setLastModifieddate(String lastModifieddate) {
        this.lastModifieddate = lastModifieddate;
    }
    public String getLastModifiedby() {
        return lastModifiedby;
    }
    public void setLastModifiedby(String lastModifiedby) {
        this.lastModifiedby = lastModifiedby;
    }

}
```

from jsp, the following tag is there for endDate. I have included start date tag as well for reference:

```
<td>Start Date</td>
                <td><form:input type="date" class="disable1" name="startdate" id="startdate" path="startDate" required="true" /></td>

                <td>End Date</td>
                <td><form:input type="date" class="disable1" name="enddate" id="enddate" path="endDate"/></td>
```

this is a ajax call so when I press a link in my preloaded jsp the /tab2 url is called, which further invokes the following on my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/tab2")
    public String redirectjsp(Map<String,Object> map){
        Project project = new Project();
        map.put("project", project);
        map.put("projectList", projectService.getAllproject());

        return "tab2";

    }
```

every thing was working fine till I added

1. endDate tag in jsp.
2. created a property in 'project' bean with it's getter and setter and also included in the constructor of the bean.
3. added a field endDate in my database in the table 'project'.

Strangely enough!! I deleted my endDate from jsp, project class and the code is up again. Then I deleted my startDate from the Project Class and still the code is running fine as if it's not fetching the startDate from the Project Class !!

I deleted the whole Project bean Class and code is still running, I don't know which Project Bean class it's referring to, or even referring or not.

Comment: can you add your controller and your JSP?

Comment: r u sure ur `Project` table has a column `endDate` ? Also, from where are you getting this error? Please post the full context.

Comment: Have you tried to clean, rebuild and redeploy your code?

Comment: `<form:input />` have different attributes: cssClass for class, path for name and id. So try to remove name and id. Here is the doc http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input

Comment: tried, but the error persists.

Comment: is your `endDate` is of type `String` or `Date` ? what is the data type in database ?

Comment: in my table, it's of type date, also in jsp the type is date. I have done everything, exactly same as it was for 'startDate'. But it's not working.

Comment: But in your class it is `String`..!!!

Comment: of course it's in String in my class and the type conversion is implicit by hibernate in case it's saving to database and the jsp implicitly render it as date since the type is date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your valuable comments. I finally found the solution and posting in case anyone else is struggling with the same problem.

Actually the metadata of my project was corrupt. I closed the eclipse, went in the workspace and deleted the .metadata folder. Then I imported the project again by Import>general>existing projects in workspace. Now everything is working as expected.

Also I am using tiles to render my output. I was changing 'tab2.jsp' and expecting the change but actually when I looked into the tiles configurer, it was configured to return tab2_update.jsp rather.

Answer (score 0):

The property enddate is not correct defined as Expression Language in one your jsp-pages.

If you are using relations between classes, you must define the property that represents the association.

Without relation:

```
${x.enddate}
```

With relation:

```
${x.class.enddate}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the jsp page can access your bean fields you could use your IDE's generate getters and setters method. it is much more accurate i think than manually typing the getters and setters.

```
source>generate setters and getters select field to generate getters and setters.
```

you can call the endDate object with EL by `${project.endDate}` and i can see in  your code that you have a project list?iterate it with foreach

import the taglib

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

iterate the list

```
<c:foreach items="projectlist" var="proj">

<c:out value="${proj.endDate}"/>

</c:foreach>
```

Comment: thanks ker p pag, for the suggestion but that's what I have done.

Comment: can you post your jsp code?where you call the endDate.

Comment: document.getElementById("releasedate").value = "<c:out value='${proj.releaseDate}'/>" ;
        document.getElementById("startdate").value = "<c:out value='${proj.startDate}'/>" ;
        document.getElementById("enddate").value = "<c:out value='${proj.endDate}'/>" ;
        document.getmentById("projstatus").value = "<c:out value='${proj.projStatus}'/>" ;

Comment: in your post it is project not proj

Comment: I have refered the project by 'proj' variable.                          <c:forEach items="${projectList}" var="proj">                  'projectList' contains the list of project.